# Set attributes object (text), with ID and NAME itself search. - KineticJS

Tags: html, object, canvas, kineticjs

I have a stage with a layer inside it and a group inside the layer.

If my object (`var complexText = new Kinetic.Text()`) has `name: 'name1'` and `id: 'id5'`,
is it possible to change the fill and text with `setFill()` and `setText()` only by using the `id`?

My code is not working:

```
var stage = new Kinetic.Stage({ ... });
var layer = new Kinetic.Layer();
var group1 = new Kinetic.Group({ draggable: false });
layer.add(group1);
stage.add(layer);

var menuTab = new Kinetic.Rect({... , id: 'id1', name: 'name1'});      
var complexText = new Kinetic.Text({... , id: 'id5', name: 'name1'});      
group1.add(menuTab);
group1.add(complexText);

menuTab.on('click', function() {
    var textChange = stage.get('#id5');  // didn't work
    // and .... var textChange = layer.get('#id5');
    // and .... var textChange = group1.get('#id5'); //didn't work

        textChange.setFill('#BB9999');
        textChange.setText('f3');
        alert( textChange.getText() );
        //this.setText('3');
    layer.draw();
});
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You have to use

```
var textChange = stage.get('#id5')[0];
// or .... var textChange = layer.get('#id5')[0];
// or .... var textChange = group1.get('#id5')[0];

textChange.setFill('#BB9999');
textChange.setText('f3');
```

Comment: Ok. Provides a similar solution use it:

`var textObjects = group1.get('#id5');
var textObject = textObjects.toArray()[0];
textObject.setText('newText');`

Comment: [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702319/kineticjs-replacing-image-within-a-group) : `var ImageObjects = selectedGroup.get("Image");
var ImageObject=ImageObjects.toArray()[0];`

Comment: If you are selecting by **ID** than we know there is only **one** object with that ID, so we don't need to use the toArray() method. If you are selecting a group of objects by **name** than the toArray method may apply.

Comment: I understand/ In the example have different ID (`'id1'`, `'id5'`), but the same NAME. I needed a theoretical training for all options. Thanks. Pointed out this [link](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/17702319/kineticjs-replacing-image-within-a-group) , and my second message to ID.

Comment: You can also select by name using something like `stage.get('.name1');` See these tutorials: [Get By Id](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shape-by-id-with-kineticjs/) [Get By Name](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shapes-by-name-with-kineticjs/) [Get By Type](http://www.html5canvastutorials.com/kineticjs/html5-canvas-select-shapes-by-type-with-kineticjs/)

Comment: Yes, if i select by type of `Kinetic.Rect`, using `stage.get('Rect')` without char '#' or '.'.

Comment: Yup That's right, that'll get all the `Kinetic.Rect` in the `stage`